# How do I code a FloatingActionButton to add a card to a list with details from another page?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, widget

Using Flutter in Android Studio

I basically want to create an action button that creates a new card in a list.

My cards are imported from a separate class which is their format, but each new card will have new data from the user. The fields are things like title, date, time etc. But I don't know how to code it to go -

Press button -> navigate to input_form.dart -> click confirm to create card -> card goes into List view with other cards made this way in chronological order.

Answer (score 0):

You can use getx or another state management but if you don't want use them you can try this.
suppose this is save button in form page, this method create a object of card class and pass it to the card list page.

```
   ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                // Create a new card model with the provided data
                CardModel newCard = CardModel(
                  title: _titleController.text,
                  date: _selectedDate,
                  time: _selectedTime,
                );

                // Pass the new card back to the previous screen
                Navigator.pop(context, newCard);
              }
            },
            child: Text('Confirm'),
          ),
```

in card list page you can create FAB like this to access card object.

```
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () async {
      // Navigate to the input form to create a new card
      final newCard = await Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => InputForm()),
      );

      // Add the new card to the list if the user confirmed the input
      if (newCard != null) {
        setState(() {
          cards.add(newCard);
          // Sort the list by date in ascending order
          cards.sort((a, b) => a.date.compareTo(b.date));
        });
      }
    },
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
  ),
```

Comment: Thanks, I will have a go at adding these details in and see how it goes!

+1